# Is this a bug in Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

I am an active Google Hangouts user, and something very weird has been happening to me since the past few days; Is the same happening to anyone else?

I usually check my Hangouts messages through Gmail (I am on Google Chrome). When I see my friends 'online', I usually send a 'hi'. Sometimes, when I close the small Hangouts tab that opens in the bottom-right, the Hangouts tab shows my friends status as - 'active 15 min ago'. The time is always 15 minutes; not more, not less.

I have a chrome version 86.0.4240.75; This "glitch" has only happened in the non-incognito mode of Chrome so far. That might also be because I haven't used Hangouts in Incognito, ever. I have NO EXTENSIONS. I am using Windows 10.

Why does this happen?

Comment: perhaps [this is the place](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/7291340?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) to report problems with this package?

Comment: @User24601 It is, but I am not sure what I witnessed, so I cannot be sure about what I should/should not do. Additionally, I want to know WHY that happens, more than than HOW to report it.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This didn't happen to me. Please add more detail like the name an version of OP as well of Chrome. Also mention if this happens using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled.

Comment: @Rubén, thanks. I have updated the question. does that help?

Comment: Just delete the cookies and clear the cache.

Comment: @Rubén, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try reset Chrome settings to default -> https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en If that doesn't work, unistall and reinstall Chrome